# Convert CSV to Nested JSON complex structure

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, nested

I'm currently new to python we have a csv file and this needs to be converted in to a Nested JSON file.

```
name      type  aitm      alitm     aaitm           adsc1   
specs     glass 70072187  ESA65Z45  ESA 65Z45       CUT TIP FG 1808-40
```

I'm trying to structure the above data in below json format

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "spec",
      "type": "glass",
      "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "aitm": {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": "70072187",
                "source": "internal",
                "locale": "en_US"
              }
            ]
          },
          "alitm": {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": "ESA65Z45",
                "source": "internal",
                "locale": "en_US"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aaitm": {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": "ESA 65Z45",
                "source": "internal",
                "locale": "en_US"
              }
            ]
          },
          "adsc1": {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": "CUT TIP FG",
                "source": "internal",
                "locale": "en_US"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above JSON there are some values which are not present in the csv source and locale which are not present in the data however i need to incorporate these values in the structure.

I have tried with python and R we couldn't succeed due to this complex JSON structure I also tried with 
    details = df.groupby(['name', 'type']).apply(
    lambda r: r[['aitm', 'alitm']].to_dict(orient='records'))

```
nested = details.unstack('name')


pprint(grouped.unstack('name').to_dict())


output = nested.apply(lambda s: [
{s.index.name: idx, 'Details': value}
for idx, value in s.items()
]).to_dict('records')

print(output)
```

The structure what I'm getting is not correct. Please suggest ways for solving this problem using python.

Comment: This seems like a relative straightforward task. What you need to do, is use the csv module, to open the csv and iterate over each line. I'm assuming that each row in the csv will be it's own JON dict?

Comment: Yes- Can you help with the code if possible. I tried but failed

Answer (score 0):

Python has wrappers for [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/) so you might be interested in the following solution that uses jq, especially as the Q indicates you have considered alternatives to python in any case.  Notice that the solution below is as "data-driven" as the data allows. In particular, arbitrarily many columns will be handled.

In the following, I've assumed the input is actually CSV (comma-separated values) and that splitting by the regex " *, *" will suffice.  If the input is more complex, then it would probably be simplest to convert it to some more regular format, e.g. TSV.

```
def toa: [splits(" *, *")];

def column($n; $headers):
  { ($headers[$n]) :
      { values: [{value: .[$n], source: "internal", locale: "en_US"}] }
  };

toa as $headers
| [ inputs
    | toa
    | {name: .[0],
       type: .[1],
       data: { attributes:
                ([range(2; $headers|length) as $col
                 | column($col; $headers) ] | add)
             }
      }]
| {entities: .}
```

#### Invocation

It's simplest to illustrate usage from the command line.  With the above program in a file named csv2json.jq, and the data in input.csv:

```
jq -R -f csv2json.jq input.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I tried to install the pyjq and i recieve a filed with error code 1. I have tried in a different workstation too i get the same error.
FYI : We are using windows

Comment: There are two python bindings available (pip install jq; pip install pyjq) but before trying the second alternative, I'd suggest installing jq directly, e.g. using `choco install jq`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The choco install jq has installed. However we are unable to execute the Invocation method since we are using a windows machine with Anaconda Jupyter IDE. Please help us on the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help with the IDE, but you should be able to run jq directly at a Windows command-line prompt. (See e.g.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands for further info.)

Comment: using powershell in Visual Studio code i was able to execute your jq script. How can i write this to a .JSON file based on every row

Comment: Congratulations. If you want one file for the second row, and another for the third row, etc., then I'd be inclined to write all the JSON to a file using jq's `-c` command-line option (which results in one JSON entity per line), and then use some other tool to write each line of this file to a separate file. If you have further questions about this, I'd suggest asking a new SO question about splitting a file by line. Be sure to add tags suggesting the kind of solution you'd be comfortable with (e.g. awk, PowerShell, python, etc, etc)